# Limiting number value in an input tag with javascript

Tags: javascript, html, input

I am creating a form and i want the input tag to accept numbers only and i also want to limit the numbers to be from 0 - 20.

This my html code:

```
<input type="text" name="three" class="actual" id="three" maxlength="2" onkeypress="return ForNumbers(event)" />
```

This is my javascript code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function ForNumbers(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
if (charCode > 31 && (charCode < 48 || charCode > 57))
    return false;
return true;
        }
    </script>
```

Comment: what is the issue with this code? any error? or any abnormal behavior??

Comment: i need an additional code to it. i want to the input tag accept only values between 0 and 20

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you need to support old browsers, try this:

```
    function ForNumbers(evt){
        var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

        if (
        //0~9
        charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57 ||
           //number pad 0~9
           charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105 ||
        //backspace
           charCode == 8 ||
        //tab
        charCode == 9 ||
        //enter
        charCode == 13 || 
        //left, right, delete..
        charCode >= 35 && charCode <= 46
        )
        {
        //make sure the new value below 20
        if(parseInt(this.value+String.fromCharCode(charCode), 10) <= 20) 
            return true;
        }

        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();

        return false;
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/3StSM/2/

It also works fine with:

```
  <input id="numIpt" type="number" min="0" max="20" maxlength="2" />
```

Comment: Thank you very much Andrew. This solves my challenge

Answer (score 10):

Should be able to do something like this:

```
if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
if (input.value > 20) input.value = 20;
```

Simple as that if that's what you mean.

You could get this to run when the value for the input changes (`onChange`) that way they can see the limit.

## Full function:

### HTML:

```
<input type="text" onchange="limiter(this);" />
```

### Javascript:

```
function limiter(input) {
   if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
   if (input.value > 100) input.value = 100;
}
```

[Working Demo](http://jsbin.com/IVAHOlu/2/edit)

Comment: or might be an alert and return false. Anyways +1

Comment: Please can i get the full script with the javascript function

Comment: @user3016488 I have made an edit to my answer, that's how I would have it. If you want it differently I'm sure you can edit it to your needs.

Comment: thanks for your effort Ruddy but its not working. I wrote this code:                <input type="text" onchange="limiter(this);" />

<script language="javascript">
function limiter(input) {
   if (input.value < 0) input.value = 0;
   if (input.value > 20) input.value = 20;
}
</script>

Answer (score 1):

Use html type number and inline elements `min="1"` and `max="20"` to limit your input field.

```
<input type="number" min="1" max="20" />
```