# HTML input only Numeric input except ^

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I used this code only numeric input but ^ char can input? How can i fix?

```
    <input type="text" onkeypress='return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57'></input>
```

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20115337/limiting-number-value-in-an-input-tag-with-javascript/20115673#20115673

Comment: Your code works fine actually. Did you used some non-english input method?

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type="text" onkeypress='return( event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode==94) '></input>
```

This will solve your purpose

```
function validateInput(evt)
{
    if ((evt.charCode >= 48 && evt.charCode <= 57) || (evt.charCode==94))
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

<input type="text" onkeypress='return validateInput(event)'></input>
```

Comment: @sugar, if you think the answer helped, don't forget to mark it as correct.

Comment: I don't wanna put ^ except your code my code accept ^^^ I don't want.

Comment: your code does not seem to except the character (^) see http://jsfiddle.net/sahilthadhani/sCxCk/1/